# Maximum Principle for the Derivatives of Parabolic PDE Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation, maximum-principle

Is there a maximum principle for the spatial derivatives of the solution of a parabolic PDE with coefficients in front of the spatial partial derivatives depending on spatial variables only, similar to the solution itself to the PDE?